# How to pass a list to a recursive function

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, recursion

I have a local list (inside a function) which I am passing to the same function's recursive call.

I am modifying the list inside the recursive call but I don't want the changes to be reflected in the original copy.

I am aware of deepcopy, but not able to put it in place. 
Any pointers?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE].

Comment: We can't show you how to put it in place if you don't post your code, can we?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best/cleanest way I found was to pass `copy.deepcopy(old_list)` in the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

If you don´t want to Change the original list, you have to create a new list and then set the new list = the original. If I understood it right

Comment: *new list = the original* will only copy the reference, not the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
old_list = [***]
new_list = old_list.copy()
```

it's working on Python3, if it doesn't work on Python2, then simply try this:

```
new_list = old_list[:]
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'copy'`

Comment: it's working on Python3, if it doesn't work on Python2, then simply try this:

    `new_list = old_list[:]`

Comment: Question is tagged 2.7.  `new_list = old_list[:]` will not be correct if the old list contains references (the references are copied), for example a list of lists or dictionaries.  `copy.deepcopy()` is much safer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing :)